# Error When Passing Post Data In Stock Screener

Tags: python, html, fastapi

I am trying select two values stock id and strategy id in order to redirect to a page that displays the data but, when I try to redirect to my strategy this error comes up:

> {"detail":[{"loc":["body","stock_id"],"msg":"field
> required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}

Here is how I set up my main:

```
@app.post("/apply_strategy")
def apply_strategy(strategy_id:int = Form(...), stock_id:int = Form(...)):
    print(stock_id, strategy_id)

    connect = sqlite3.connect(config.DB_FILE)
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    print('Test here')


    cursor.execute("""
        INSERT INTO stock_strategy (stock_id, strategy_id) VALUES (?, ?)
    """, (stock_id, strategy_id))

    connect.commit()

    return RedirectResponse(url=f"/strategy/{strategy_id}", status_code=303)


@app.get("/strategy/{strategy_id}")
def strategy(request: Request, strategy_id):
    
    print('test')
    connect = sqlite3.connect(config.DB_FILE)
    connect.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    cursor = connect.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT id, name
        FROM strategy
        WHERE id = ?
    """, (strategy_id,))

    strategy = cursor.fetchone()

    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT symbol, name
        FROM stock JOIN stock_strategy on stock_strategy.stock_id = stock.id
        WHERE strategy_id = ?
    """, (strategy_id,))

    stocks = cursor.fetchall()

    return templates.TemplateResponse("strategy.html", {"request": request, "stocks": stocks, "strategy": strategy})
```

I am passing data from data_strategies to my strategy page:

```
<form method="post" action ="/apply_strategy" >
  <select name = "strategy_id">
    {% for strategy in strategies %}
      <option value="{{ strategy.id }}">{{ strategy.name }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <input type="text" value="{{ stock.id }}" name="{{ stock.id }}"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Apply Strategy" />

</form>
```

Once the form is submitted I get the error. Could someone show me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: the route names are inconsistent.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem does not come from the RedirectResponse, you are sending a request with the wrong parameters to your backend API.

The name field in your from should be `stock_id`, because your backend expects a JSON object with two keys, and the keys should be exact keys with your endpoints parameters.

```js
 <input type="text" value="{{ stock.id }}" name="stock_id"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Apply Strategy" />
```

Also, you have another problem in your `/strategy/{strategy_id}` endpoint. You have a path parameter but you declared it without a type annotation.

```py
@app.get("/strategy/{strategy_id}")
def strategy(request: Request, strategy_id: int):
    ...
```

You should type annotate your every parameter, otherwise, FastAPI assumes it is a body parameter.